# Function is not called after purchase made

Tags: flutter

I'm studying Flutter and I'm at a tremendous burn out. I have a package that initiates a purchase of a consumable product and right after the purchase performs a function.

The problem is happening after the purchase is made, my post-purchase function is simply not triggered. Can anyone give me a light on this issue?

It's really annoying because I need to build and publish to Google Play Console in closed test every time I need to test the billing library.

I use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/super_easy_in_app_purchase

I have an onTap that starts the purchase:

```
ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.payments),
    title: Text('Add balance'),
    subtitle: Text(r'Add $1.99 to your balance'),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
    onTap: () async {
        await inAppPurchase.startPurchase('product_1.99',
        isConsumable: true);
    },
),
```

Here I define what is done when the purchase is made:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    inAppPurchase = SuperEasyInAppPurchase(
      whenSuccessfullyPurchased: <String, Function>{
        'product_1.99': () async => _createTransaction("1.99"),
        'product_3.99': () async => _createTransaction("3.99"),
        'product_9.99': () async => _createTransaction("9.99"),
        'product_19.99': () async => _createTransaction("19.99"),
        'product_49.99': () async => _createTransaction("49.99"),
        'product_99.99': () async => _createTransaction("99.99"),
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    inAppPurchase.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

And this is the function that inserts the transaction into a backend:

```
_createTransaction(String amount) async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    String? device;
    var response;

    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
        device = '${androidInfo.brand} (${androidInfo.model})';
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
        device = '${iosInfo.utsname.machine}';
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      device = 'unknown';
    }

    setState(() {
      saving = true;
    });

    var data = {
      'mail': GetStorage('UserInfo').read('userMail'),
      'amount': amount,
      'device': device
    };

    try {
      response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse('https://myapisite/app/1/user/transaction.php'),
          body: json.encode(data));
    } on TimeoutException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        saving = false;
      });

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Something wrong'),
            content: new Text(
                'Try again'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        saving = false;
      });

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Something wrong'),
            content: new Text(
                'Try again'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var transactionRequest = TransactionRequest.fromJson(userMap);

      if (transactionRequest.success) {
        setState(() {
          saving = false;
        });

        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text(transactionRequest.title),
              content: new Text(transactionRequest.message),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: new Text("OK"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        setState(() {
          saving = false;
        });

        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text(transactionRequest.title),
              content: new Text(transactionRequest.message),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: new Text("OK"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Error'),
            content: new Text(
                'Error code: ${response.statusCode}.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

It works normal if I replace what I do when the purchase is made by a print. But it doesn't call the function that inserts the transaction into the backend. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure because I haven't tested it, but could it be you have to add an `await` statement before calling `_createTransaction`?

Comment: Not work, https://prnt.sc/1rw19k4. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: I think ```_createTransaction``` should return Future as you're making an async call to it.

Comment: Not work using Future :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not triggered because the package fails. Due to lack of maintenance I gave up this package and started using another one. The issue was resolved when switching packages.